# The event creation screen for chat room events is kind of broken

Tags: feature-request, bug, chat, events

I created an event and the default date was tomorrow. Why tomorrow? Why not today? Or next week? I think that the default should be today's date.

The time field needs a colon. Typing "2200" breaks the page. You need to type "22:00". Or use the time picker, which works correctly, of course.

The only time zone is UTC. Why can't I schedule in my local time and have it convert? Or pick a time zone.

Comment: 1. No. Tomorrow is a fine default. Some advance warning is appreciated. 2. Agreed, kinda. I have nothing against typing the colon, but omitting it shouldn't break the page. 3. Meh. Most events need to be scheduled internationally anyway, so you'll need to worry about the time in different time zones before deciding on a time, at which point you might as well enter the UTC date. And this tremendously reduces the possible confusion between days.

Comment: A default time zone of UTC would be fine with me, but I'd like to choose.

Comment: Making the default tomorrow isn't going to get people to move their events to tomorrow, it's just going to make them change the value or mess up and schedule the event wrong. People are going to schedule the event when they think of it; nothing on the page is going to affect that

Comment: Most events are usually announced in advance... no it's not going to make people change it's more logical for today. **If they are going to mess up the date in simple form, they *shouldn't* have access to controls like that.**